# What is the best CMS for developing in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint, content-management-system, umbraco

It is for implementing a public website with more than 100 content pages and severals subdomains and cultures. The design is already done (HTML,CSS), so the CMS should be flexible and easy to control the presentation details.

Because that, I thought to use ASP.NET MVC4 to control the output HTML, and I am looking for a good CMS to work with.

I've been recommended to use Sharepoint, but I think it is not a good idea for a public website. I am thinking of Umbraco CMS as it integrates great with MVC.

Any other CMS to take into account?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Havent used other CMS out there but heavily use Umbraco and think its best .net CMS to use because you can make it as complex or as simple as you want , supports multi domains and cultures with the use of dictionaries for the different cultures and most important of all a great community and its free.

Comment: +1 for Umbraco. I've been working with it for years and prefer it over every CMS I've worked with. It allows you to customize the backend to give your content managers as much or as little freedom as they need without the fear of destroying the site. It also has great User management options that allow you setup workflows for updating content. Also, the updated UI for Umbraco 7.x is pretty hot (responsive, intuitive, etc...) Read more on their site: http://umbraco.com/why-umbraco

Answer (score 1):

Orchard CMS is a good choice. It provides lots of features. 
http://www.orchardproject.net/